# Cannot find method getBindingAdapterPosition() in RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

The RecyclerView docs mentions a public method - **getBindingAdapterPosition**.
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getBindingAdapterPosition()

But i cannot seem to find it.

[image]

What am i missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This method `getBindingAdapterPosition()` is yet not available on stable release. It is still in `Alpha` phase, if you want to use anyway update your dependence in gradle as

`implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha03'` and this method will be there.